# chrome repeating html table header even if the table is ended

Tags: html, google-chrome

Recently I am facing an issue in Chrome . While printing ,Chrome is repeating the header under thead for every html table to next page even if the same is ended in first page .

This is to print multiple bills of different customers where each page is a bill having same template. In html page it is showing perfectly but while printing repeating headers of previous page although table is ended . We are using this software for more than a year but never faced the same even in chrome earlier . This is working properly in Microsoft Edge .

Can someone please throw some light on this .

Comment: Lights must focus on code (HTML + CSS), _better_ if stripped down to the smallest valid snippet to reproduce this issue. I'd say your HTML (or your CSS) is invalid but...

Comment: This is working perfectly when viewed in browser . From Edge print is coming properly . Even in chrome it worked months before . I could find discussions on chrome failing to repeat headers if the table continues to next page e,g, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826 . Here it is , priniting header even if the table has ended .

Comment: Please check this sample <html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Bill</th>
<th>Payment</th>
</tr>
</thead><thead>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">Rs. 28290.00/-</td>
<td>received</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p style="page-break-before: always">
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Bill</th>
<th>Payment</th>
</tr>
</thead><thead>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">Rs. 28290.00/-</td>
<td>received</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body></html>

Comment: And that will repeat header on next page? Which doctype you have? Try closing `<p>` tag...

Comment: No luck! Have put <p style="page-break-before: always"/> . Also <p style="page-break-before: always"></p> . Result is same as before . I have not specified any doctype but tried <!doctype html> now in this test html , Please note this issue was reported first by various client groups . So this is happening in other machines as well .

Comment: I suspect this is a fairly recent bug introduced after they fixed the original issue with _not_ repeating table headers (which is the issue in 24826 that you linked to). See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=631222. It should be fixed in Chrome 53.0.2785.146